# How to store Golang big.Int into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, bigint

I have a struct referencing a *big.Int. When storing this struct naively into MongoDB (using the official driver) the field turns to be nil when fetching the struct back. What is the proper/best way to store a big.Int into MongoDB?

```golang
    type MyStruct struct {
        Number *big.Int
    }

    nb := MyStruct{Number: big.NewInt(42)}
    r, _ := db.Collection("test").InsertOne(context.TODO(), nb)

    result := &MyStruct{}
    db.Collection("test").FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"_id", r.InsertedID}}).Decode(result)
    fmt.Println(result) // <== Number will be 0 here
```

My best idea so far would be to create a wrapper around big.Int that implements `MarshalBSON` and `UnmarshalBSON` (which I am not even sure how to do properly to be honest). But that'd be quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible implementation I came up with that stores the big.Int as plain text into MongoDb. It is also possible to easily store as byte array  by using methods `Bytes` and `SetBytes` of big.Int instead of `MarshalText`/`UnmarshalText`.

```golang
package common

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

type BigInt struct {
    i *big.Int
}

func NewBigInt(bigint *big.Int) *BigInt {
    return &BigInt{i: bigint}
}

func (bi *BigInt) Int() *big.Int {
    return bi.i
}
func (bi *BigInt) MarshalBSON() ([]byte, error) {
    txt, err := bi.i.MarshalText()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    a, err := bson.Marshal(map[string]string{"i": string(txt)})
    return a, err
}

func (bi *BigInt) UnmarshalBSON(data []byte) error {
    var d bson.D
    err := bson.Unmarshal(data, &d)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if v, ok := d.Map()["i"]; ok {
        bi.i = big.NewInt(0)
        return bi.i.UnmarshalText([]byte(v.(string)))
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("key 'i' missing")
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to MarshalBSON a `big.Int` to a `string` directly?

Answer (score -3):

> the field turns to be nil when fetching the struct back

The reason why it returns 0, is because there is no `bson` mapping available for [big.Int](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewInt). If you check the document inserted into MongoDB collection you should see something similar to below:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "number": {}
}
```

Where there is no value stored in `number` field.

> What is the proper/best way to store a big.Int into MongoDB?

Let's first understand what `BigInt` is. Big integer data type is intended for use when integer values might exceed the range that is supported by the int data type. The range is -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) with storage size of 8 bytes. Generally this is used in [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

In Go, you can use a more precise integer types. Available [built-in types](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/) int8, int16, int32, and int64 (and their unsigned counterparts) are best suited for data. The counterparts for big integer in Go is [int64](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int64). With range -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, and storage size of 8 bytes.

Using [mongo-go-driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver),you can just use `int64` which will be converted to [bson RawValue.Int64](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#RawValue.Int64). For example:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Number  int64
}

collection := db.Collection("tests")
nb := MyStruct{Number: int64(42)}
r, _ := collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), nb)

var result MyStruct
collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"_id", r.InsertedID}}).Decode(&result)
```

Comment: big.Int can be much larger than int64